# Low latency / Low Priority loop. Best method

Tags: c++, loops, low-latency, memory-consumption

Let me start be saying that this question differs from the many low latency posts I've found. I'm not trying to get the most speed possible out of a calculation. This loop is for a temperature probe. I have a function

```
tZone1Temp()
```

which when run returns an integer value. I want to loop this and many more like it for an extended period of time. A polling rate any faster than 10/sec is useless. What I'm looking for is a slow loop that will not consume resources.

The only way I know how to slow down a loop is by writing another loop. I thought about using time.h to monitor the RTC but I'm not sure if that’s more efficient.

I'm sure there is some boilerplate code out there for this type of stuff but I can't find it.

Comment: Is a sleep not good enough?

Comment: Wow, that's easy. Honestly, I didn't even know there was a sleep function within the c library.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I would ask if it is a bad thing that I use the libraries somewhat interchangeably but that would derail this topic, Thanks

Comment: For a thread that needs to wake up 10 times per second, inserting a call to usleep(100000) into your loop should do the trick -- or if you want to run under Windows, call Sleep(100) instead.

Comment: If you are using C++11 you can use the standard library function: std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);